# I'm trying to store lists in python and then match with user input

Tags: python

I'm trying to store some currencies in python. Then if the user input of the currency from with the first thing in the row and the user input of currency to matches the second thing in the row then use the exchange rate(the 3rd thing in the list)

```
               exchange_rate=(("pound", "euro", "1.21"),
                               ("euro", "pound", "0.82"),
                               ("pound", "dollar", "1.68"),
                               ("dollar", "pound", "0.59"),
                               ("pound", "yen", "171.71"),
                               ("yen", "pound", "0.0058"),
                               ("euro", "dollar", "1.38"),
                               ("dollar", "euro", "0.72"),
                               ("euro", "yen", "141.45"),
                               ("yen", "euro", "0.0071"),
                               ("dollar", "yen", "102.18")
                               ("yen", "dollar", "0.0098"))
```

and later in the program:

```
                for rows in exchange_rate:
                        if currency_from==exchange_rate[0] and currency_to==exchange_rate[1]:
                             exchange=exchange_rate[2]
                             answer=input("Would you like to use this currency:",exchange,"or input your own?")
```

I'm taking all the user input as strings just to make it easier to match with the strings in the list.
I don't want to use a csv file.
It keeps giving me an error:

```
                 ("yen", "dollar", "0.0098"))
                TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I haven't used this website that much so I don't really know how and if I am allowed to awards points to the best answer (but if you let me know how I will do it)

Also I'm not really new to python but I don't know much either.
I appreciate any help/advice I can get. 
Thank you for taking the time to read this.

```
           def rates():
               global exchange
               global exchange_rate
               exchange_rate = {("pound", "euro"): 1.21,
                 ("euro", "pound"): 0.82,
                 ("pound", "dollar"): 1.68,
                 ("dollar", "pound"): 0.59,
                 ("pound", "yen"): 171.71,
                 ("yen", "pound"): 0.0058,
                 ("euro", "dollar"): 1.38,
                 ("dollar", "euro"): 0.72,
                 ("euro", "yen"): 141.45,
                 ("yen", "euro"): 0.0071,
                 ("dollar", "yen"): 102.18,
                 ("yen", "dollar"): 0.0098}
exchange = exchange_rate[currency_from, currency_to]
def amount():
    global amount
    amount=str(input("What is the amount you wish to convert?: "))

def currency_from():
    global currency_from
    currency_from=str(input("Please type in your chosen currency: "))

def currency_to():
    global currency_to
    currency_to=str(input("Please type in your chosen currency: "))

def exchangerate():
    global answer
    global rate
    global total
    global rates
    global total1
    found=False
    count=0
    while count ==0 and not found:
       if currency_from!= exchange_rate[currency_from] and currency_to !=exchange_rate[currency_to]:
            count=count+1
     else:
            found=True
            currency_from== exchange_rate[currency_from] and currency_to==exchange_rate[currency_to]
            rate=exchange_rate[2]

answer=str(input("Would you like to use this xchange rate :",rate))

if answer== "yes":
    total=amount*rate
    print(amount, currency_from, "is:",total,currency_to)
else:
    rates=float(input("Enter rate: "))
    total1=amount*rates
    print(amount, currency_from, "is:",total1,currency_to)
#main
print("Welcome! This program is only viable for the following    currencies:dollar,euro,yen,pound")
amount()
currency_from()
currency_to()
rates()
exchangerate()
```

please note that the indenting is correct in the program but when i copied it into here it might have changed.

Comment: That's not a list, it's a tuple. The difference is in the parentheses `()`, instead of square brackets, `[]`. And `is not callable` means that you tried to call it, like a function. i.e., it parsed it like someTuple(something)

Comment: You should probably be using a dictionary.

Comment: So, are you calling a tuple (like a function)? It won't work that way. Besides, the for loop appears wrong, since instead of using `rows` the code is calling the first tuple within the exchange-rate tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple typographical error. You are missing `,` after the second to the last tuple in your tuple of tuples (`exchange_rate`):

Here is the correct version:

```
exchange_rate=(("pound", "euro", "1.21"),
               ("euro", "pound", "0.82"),
               ("pound", "dollar", "1.68"),
               ("dollar", "pound", "0.59"),
               ("pound", "yen", "171.71"),
               ("yen", "pound", "0.0058"),
               ("euro", "dollar", "1.38"),
               ("dollar", "euro", "0.72"),
               ("euro", "yen", "141.45"),
               ("yen", "euro", "0.0071"),
               ("dollar", "yen", "102.18"), # this line was missing a comma
               ("yen", "dollar", "0.0098"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `exchange_rate` a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), instead of a tuple:

```
exchange_rate = {("pound", "euro"): 1.21,
                  ("euro", "pound"): 0.82,
                  ("pound", "dollar"): 1.68,
                  ("dollar", "pound"): 0.59,
                  ("pound", "yen"): 171.71,
                  ("yen", "pound"): 0.0058,
                  ("euro", "dollar"): 1.38,
                  ("dollar", "euro"): 0.72,
                  ("euro", "yen"): 141.45,
                  ("yen", "euro"): 0.0071,
                  ("dollar", "yen"): 102.18,
                  ("yen", "dollar"): 0.0098}
```

Then you could eliminate the `for-loop` and change:

```
if currency_from==exchange_rate[0] and currency_to==exchange_rate[1]:
     exchange=exchange_rate[2]
```

into

```
exchange = exchange_rate[currency_from, currency_to]
```

Use a tuple or list when the *order* of the items is important. Use a dict when you want to look up values based on a key.

---

There's many things you could change, such as removing the global statements, and using return values from your function calls. But here I'll focus on just the two changes needed to get your code running using a `dict`:

```
def rates():
    global exchange
    global exchange_rate
    exchange_rate = {
        ("pound", "euro"): 1.21,
        ("euro", "pound"): 0.82,
        ("pound", "dollar"): 1.68,
        ("dollar", "pound"): 0.59,
        ("pound", "yen"): 171.71,
        ("yen", "pound"): 0.0058,
        ("euro", "dollar"): 1.38,
        ("dollar", "euro"): 0.72,
        ("euro", "yen"): 141.45,
        ("yen", "euro"): 0.0071,
        ("dollar", "yen"): 102.18,
        ("yen", "dollar"): 0.0098}

def amount():
    global amount
    amount = float(input("What is the amount you wish to convert?: "))  # 2

def currency_from():
    global currency_from
    currency_from = str(input("Please type in your chosen currency: "))

def currency_to():
    global currency_to
    currency_to = str(input("Please type in your chosen currency: "))

def exchangerate():
    global answer
    global rate
    global total
    global rates
    global total1
    found = False
    rate = exchange_rate[currency_from, currency_to]       # 1
    answer = str(
        input("Would you like to use this xchange rate : {}".format(rate)))

    if answer == "yes":
        total = amount * rate
        print(amount, currency_from, "is:", total, currency_to)
    else:
        rates = float(input("Enter rate: "))
        total1 = amount * rates
        print(amount, currency_from, "is:", total1, currency_to)

# main
print("Welcome! This program is only viable for the following    currencies:dollar,euro,yen,pound")
amount()
currency_from()
currency_to()
rates()
exchangerate()
```

1. The purpose of the dict is to allow you to look up the exchange rate
   without using the `while-loop`.
2. To facilitate math, the amount should be a float or decimal, not a
   str.

Comment: Dear Sir/Mrs, I've never used that before so it's completely new. To be honest I don't really know how to use what you've advised me to do. If I use the exchange= exchange_rate[] then how do I say is the user exchange from==exchange_rate[0] and how do I call the exchange rate(the 3rd thing in the bracket)? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry; I really don't understand your question. But if you read through [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) I think your question may be resolved.

Comment: I've basically written the whole program how I think it should work but I keep getting this error:

Comment: exchange_rate()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: The error message occurs because the parentheses in `exchange_rate()` tell Python you want to call the object `exchange-rate`. That would make sense if it were a function. But not if `exchange_rate` is a `dict`. The solution is to remove the parentheses. Maybe you meant to use brackets? If you would like more help, please post your code.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It was totally my mistake.

Comment: The code is too long to post in this comment. Is it ok if I post it under a different question?

Comment: Yes, you could post another question (if you feel this one has been answered), or edit this question.

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you for taking the time to look at this.I know it's kind of a mess but I'm trying.

Comment: WOW! It works. Thank you so much for taking the time. I have definitely learned a lot. Your first comment: I wasn't sure about the dict but thank you for explaining that. The second comment: In my mind I was going to change the string into a float later because I thought the answer had to be a string in order to match the currency_from but clearly I had forgotten to do that. This was an excellent answer and the program works. I have 1 reputation-is there a way of rewarding this as a best answer? Happy Easter and many thanks.